# C++ Create shared_ptr from Object

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, shared-ptr

So on my header file I have this declaration:

```
typedef std::map<const std::string, std::shared_ptr<House> > myHouseMap;
myHouseMap _myHouseMap;
```

On my source file I can insert an object in my map like this:

```
_myHouseMap.insert(std::pair<const std::string, std::shared_ptr<House>>("apartment", std::make_shared<House>("apartment")));
```

But now, I need to return the reference of the object.
Therefore, I need to create first the object, add him to the map, and return the reference to it.

```
House& Obj::CreateHouse (const char *name)
{
     House aaa ("apartment");
    _myHouseMap.insert(std::pair<const std::string, std::shared_ptr<House>>(aaa)); <--- ERROR!
     return &aaa;
}
```

**How can I, after creating an Object, create a shared_ptr from it, and insert into a map?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply construct the shared pointer first rather than inline when inserting it into the map.

```
House& Obj::CreateHouse(const char *name)
{
    // make the ptr first!
    auto aaa = std::make_shared<House>("apartment");
    _myHouseMap.insert(std::make_pair("apartment", aaa));
    return *aaa;
}
```

Comment: Re "You simply need to construct the shared pointer first", no that's not *necessary*, although it's simplest. As an alternative one can create an object with `shared_from_this` support.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious do we need to use `retrun *(aaa.get())` to match the return type

Comment: @Steephen No. `shared_ptr` overloads [`operator*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*) to return a reference to the managed type.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thanks. Great to know that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create object House pointer using `new` operator to initialize the `shared_ptr`. And you can't return reference of a local variable so returns House object pointer. And you have to pass the custom deleter to take care the cleaning process for the `shared_ptr` in that case.

```
House* Obj::CreateHouse (const char *name)
{
     House* aaa = new Hash("apartment");
    _myHouseMap.insert(std::pair<const std::string, std::shared_ptr<House>>(aaa,[=](House * aaa) {delete aaa;}));
     return aaa;
}
```

Comment: Re "You need to create object House pointer using new operator", no that's not *necessary*, although it's simplest. As an alternative you can specify an appropriate deleter for a `shared_ptr` to an object that guaranteed outlives the map. Also, for the code above, it would avoid one costly dynamic allocation to use `make_shared`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks to it point out, I corrected the statement